# Bootstrap carousel content disappears unexpectedly after a delay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, bootstrap-5

I tried to put a carousel inside a section of my website (using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap 5), but the problem is after a little time all the content and the carousel inside that section disappear, then you need to reload the page again, and that disappears again and again.

```
<section class="bg-info text-dark text-center text-sm-start"data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item active bg-light">
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">

                <!-- carousel -->

                <div class="carousel slide " id="demo" data-bs-ride="carousel">

                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>

                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>

                        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                          <img src="/images/very.jpg" class="d-block width1" alt="...">
                          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-sm-block">
                            <h5>First slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="/images/pubg.jpg" class="d-block width1" alt="...">
                          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-sm-block">
                            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="/images/pes.jpg" class="d-block width1" alt="...">
                          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-sm-block">
                            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>

                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- carousel -->

                <div class="divtwo">

                    <h1 id="headerOne1" class="text-warning mx-5 px-1 d-sm-block img-fluid w-50 w-ms-auto">Best <span class="text-info">Games</span> </h1>

                    <p class="lead paragraph mx-5 px-1">Want more amazing games..?</p>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn1 btn-outline-warning">Recommended</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data-bs-ride="carousel"` from your section and `"carousel-item active"` from your div.

Here the results,

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<section class="bg-info text-dark text-center text-sm-start" >

  <div class="bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">

        <!-- carousel -->

        <div class="carousel slide " id="demo" data-bs-ride="carousel">

          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>

            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>

            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/720/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-sm-block ">
                <h5>First slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/720/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-sm-block ">
                <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/720/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-sm-block">
                <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>

          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
        </div>

        <!-- carousel -->

        <div class="divtwo">

          <h1 id="headerOne1" class="text-warning mx-5 px-1 d-sm-block img-fluid w-50 w-ms-auto">Best <span class="text-info">Games</span> </h1>

          <p class="lead paragraph mx-5 px-1">Want more amazing games..?</p>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn1 btn-outline-warning">Recommended</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you very much mister Aksal, it works and you help me very well thank you.